# Gfci installation

Tags: wiring

I'm having problems with Gfci tripping. My outlet box has 6 wires...2 white, 2 black & 2 red wires. The 2 black wires are controlled by a socket/switch on lower part of the wall (turns on outdoor socket) and the red wires are controlled by a wall switch located on a different wall. I connected the 2 white wires to the back of the Gfci in the holes that are clearly marked "white". I then connected the 2 red wires to the 2 holes clearly marked "hot".  I turn the power back on and both the red and green light indicators are on and test it and it works fine but when I plugged in a small lamp to test it the Gfci trips? I capped the 2 black wires. I tried another Gfci just in case and it still trips the same. So I took out the red wires and capped them and inserted the black wires in the the holes marked hot. This works fine and there is no tripping on the Gfci but I want to be able to use the wall switch witch controls the red wires. In short, red wires trip but black wires don't. I hope this makes sense? Can anyone help?  Much appreciated. [image][image]

Comment: Sounds like you may be picking up a different neutral on the switched light causing an imbalance in the circuit.

Comment: Meaning I have the white wires crossed?

Comment: That is what it sounds like to me or a white from another circuit in the light or outlet.

Comment: I'll check that out. Thank you for the response!

Comment: If what Ed has said has helped, great.  Otherwise I need more information.

Comment: Hi Paul, what info do you need?

Comment: I'm not sure because I just swapped the red wires with the black. The white wires are installed correctly I think.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the involved boxes?

Comment: Sorry I can't post a photo of the box until tomorrow.